# Sony Xperia z: Hard reset with hardware buttons

Tags: sony-xperia-z

My phone's touchscreen does not work so I want to hard reset my phone to see if it helps but there is a problem, How? I can't go to my phone's setting because

1. Touchscreen does not work
2. My device is locked and requires password (I have password but I can't enter it)

Answer (score 0):

RESET

1. While the device is on, press and hold the Power and Volume Up keys.
2. Wait for the screen to shut off and the device to vibrate once (about 3 seconds).
3. Release the keys once the screen has shut off.
4. Press the power key to turn the device back on.

Master Reset feature with hardware keys is not yet supported for your phone. It can only be done with touch screen

https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-6722